# using Map in BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-services, angular7

```
           @Injectable()
           export class GlobalService {

           private variables: Map<number, Variable>;

           private observableVariables: BehaviorSubject<Map<number, 
            Variable>>;

          constructor() {
          this.variables = new Map<number, Variable>();
          this.observableVariables = new BehaviorSubject(new Map<number, 
           Variable>());
          }

          addVariable(index: number, variable:Variable) {
          this.variables.set(index, variable);
           }

          public getVariable(index:number):Variable {
          return this.variables.get(index);
          }

          public updateVariableType(index:number, type:VariableType){
           let variable = this.variables.get(index);
            variable.updateType(type);
          }
          public updateVariableName(index:number, name:String){
            let variable = this.variables.get(index);
            variable.updateName(type);
          }
          public updateAllComponents(){
          return this.observableVariables.next(this.variables);
          }
         }
```

I am using a Global service to which the components subscribe. I am using a map data structure to save the variables with the respective index. When a new component subscribes to this service will the new component gets all the data in the Map or only the last added one? The senario in my case is the new component should get all the data from the Map not just the last added one. And how to broadcast only the variables that has both name and type populated through updateVariableType and updateVariableName?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Map structure, or is that just your custom struct? What you also could do is use the BehaviousSubject as a store (so also for add/get/update) and then notify all subscribers.

Comment: "When a new component subscribes to this service will the new component gets all the data in the Map or only the last added one?" --> have you tried it? Maybe you can setup a plunkr code with a minimal example